# Problems with vite.config.ts and Contentful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, contentful

I am building a React App. I installed aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react, and then updated my vite.config.ts as follows:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env,
    'global': {}
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: /^~.+/,
        replacement: (val) => {
          return val.replace(/^~/, "");
        },
      },
      {
        find: './runtimeConfig', replacement: './runtimeConfig.browser',
      }
    ],
  },
})
```

However, after doing so, I ran npm run build, which could not be completed, as Contentful dependancy crashed in the project, with the following message:
'Could not resolve "./create-{}-options" from "node_modules/contentful/dist/es-modules/contentful.js'

I've been searching for hours any solution without success.

Does anyone know what's going on or any idea that can help to solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: alias config replacement is a string type, you can try like this: `{find: /~/, replacement: ''}`, or delete this alias item and then build,  check if there is an error message.